# Creating shapefile file with Fiona and GeoPandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona, pandas

I am trying to create a shapefile and a geojson using geopandas and fiona.

```
import fiona
import fiona.crs
```

...

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'],df['latitude'])]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

some more stuffs and finally:

```
gdf.to_file('localization/shapefiles/localizaciones.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

but the .prj file is in blank. Then the projection is wrong.

I am writing  the content of the the .prj file after the file is created in blank, but the crs problems still in progress either in geojson file or gpx files. No crs is created

Comment: What versions of GeoPandas and Fiona do you have?

Comment: GPX is always EPSG:4326 and so is GeoJSON by the current specification https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946 so there is no crs problem with them.

Comment: Why do you mention GPX? As for the question, it seems clear from the code that a shapefile is written. Then a prj file is needed

Comment: About gpx and the geojson is my mistake. Nothing have to do

Comment: fiona version 1.7.13  Pandas version 0.23.0 Geopandas 0.4.0

Comment: GeoJSON is not EPSG:4326, it's CRS:84, that is different axis ordering

Answer (score 1):

Found two solutions to have coordinate reference system defined in the output shapefile: Proj4 style mappings and WKT strings (source: [Fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/__init__.py)). The OGC WKT strings can be found on [spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/).

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list)]
#crs1 = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}         # Does NOT work
crs2 = {'proj': 'longlat', 'ellps': 'WGS84', 'datum': 'WGS84', 'no_defs': True}     # Works
#crs3 = 'EPSG:4326'       # Does NOT work
crs4 = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",' \
       'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,' \
       'AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],' \
       'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],' \
       'UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,' \
       'AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],' \
       'AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'     # Works

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], crs=crs4, geometry=geometry)
points.to_file(filename='points.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Previous solution was on Windows 7 OS using geopandas installation from conda. On Ubuntu 18.04 OS there was no problem creating the projection text in the output shapefile with { 'init': 'epsg:4326'} or 'EPSG:4326'. It worked with both the geopandas installation of conda and conda-forge.

Comment: EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry should be used wherever possible (as they are authority that define EPSG codes...)  ~ http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326